# Are there rules how 'g' is pronounced as /j/ or /g/?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

I'm not an native English speaker, and sometimes I'm confused with the pronunciation of 'g' and 'j' in words. It seems that 'j' is usually pronounced as /dʒ/ for example "job", "jaw". But 'g' can be pronounced as /dʒ/ or /g/. For example "gorgeous" is pronounced as  /'ɡɔrdʒəs/, but "georgia" is pronounced as /'dʒɔ:dʒjə/. So I have two questions:

1. How could I know whether I should pronouciation as /g/ or /dʒ/ if I see a word start with letter 'g'?
2. How could I know whether the word starts with a 'g' or 'j' if the pronunciation start with a /g/?

Comment: The best rule is to remember each word on its own. However, one particular pattern that comes to mind is that g is pronounced /dʒ/ before e, i, y in word *of latin origin*.

Comment: In the histories of some Romance languages, /g/ became /dʒ/ before /e/ and /i/, but this was not reflected in spelling.  English borrowed many words along with their spellings from those languages.

Comment: [There is no rule connecting English spelling and pronunciation.](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/pronunciation-vs-spelling/info) You have to learn each how to spell each new word you hear independently from every other word you hear.

Comment: I think in #2 you mean if the pronunciation starts with a /dʒ/?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As to the letter g the general rule is g + "dark vowels (a o u) is pronounced as /g/ as in garden gold guard guess guide gust. In French words such as guard, guide the u is a mere graphic sign indicating that g is spoken /g/. This u is inserted before frontal vowels such as e or i.

g before frontal vowels e and i is spoken /ʤ/ as a rule. Gina, gin.
This is true mostly for French or Latin words.

These rules of thumb have quite a number of exceptions. But only the exceptions have to be learnt, and ge/gi in Germanic words as geese, gift remains /g/.

Comment: soooo many exceptions in English https://www.thefreedictionary.com/words-that-start-with-gi

Answer (score 3):

The letter `g` can indeed be pronounced as [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) symbols [d͡ʒ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%CA%92) or [ɡ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C9%A1) whereas the letter `j` is overwhelmingly d͡ʒ (and pretty much never ɡ).

[English lacks consistent spelling→pronuciation rules](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/pronunciation-vs-spelling/info).  It really depends on what language the word was plucked from ... and when.  Words that pre-date the standardization that took place from the first dictionaries tend to be rather arbitrary since English lacked spelling conventions at the time.

Here's a nice adage on that topic:

> English has pursued other languages down alleyways to beat them unconscious and rifle their pockets for new vocabulary. — James Nicoll

... which is to say:  Good luck, you'll need it!

The best way to learn this distinction (though I'm not happy about it) is to watch television shows and movies that are in English, ideally that use accents you'd like to learn (e.g. American shows tend to use American Broadcaster English while shows from India will have any number of regional accents that may not be intelligible to people from Ireland or Alabama).

Comment: Well … /j/ is **mostly** [ʤ]. There are plenty of exceptions, of course, as with everything else in English: _marijuana_ (silent), _junta_ [h], _Hallelujah_ [j], _jeté_ [ʒ], etc. But in general, it is one of the less troublesome letters in the alphabet, since most words where it’s _not_ pronounced [ʤ] are quite obvious foreign loans that tend to look un-English in other ways as well.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet is correct.  This is a good example of that concept of English borrowing words and not bothering to standardize their spelling.  I've changed my "always" claim to something more accurate.

Comment: Also, once spelling on a word standardized (at least since the popularization of dictionaries in the 1700's), it rarely changes much. Thus often a word that used to be pronounced roughly similar to its spelling is no longer pronounced that way in much of the English-speaking world. My favorite guide for this is hymnals. For [some of the older hymns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Wesley#Hymns), it can be really surprising to see what apparently was a rhyming pair of words back in the 18th and 19th centuries.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You do hear English speakers occasionally using [h] in *marijuana*, just never the original [x].  And no, there is no hidden meaning in the previous sentence. :)